# Antd table doesn't re-render with new data

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-context

I am using React context and antd design table, when context state "transaction" changed after API all, component re-rendered, I can see updated transaction with console.log, but seems  component not getting new transaction, the "Target" column still shows old target data. please let me what went wrong, Thank you!

```
const { transaction, getTransactions, deleteTransaction, updateTransaction } = useContext(GlobalContext);

column = {
      title: "Target",
      dataIndex: ["analysis", "Target"],
    },

return (
    <div className="table-container">
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={transaction}
        size="middle"
        rowKey="_id"
        pagination={{ pageSize: 15 }}
      />
```

Comment: Make sure you've wrapped the App with <GlobalContext.Provider> and written createContext before.

Comment: I do have <GlobalContext.Provider> wrapped,  table can be updated when add new transaction or delete one. But this one 'target' nested in analysis just doesn't work properly.